# How do I substitute Guice modules with fake test modules for unit tests?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, guice

Here's how we are using [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) in a new application:

```
public class ObjectFactory {
  private static final ObjectFactory instance = new ObjectFactory();
  private final Injector injector;

  private ObjectFactory() throws RuntimeException {
    this.injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module1());
  }

  public static final ObjectFactory getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

  public TaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
    return injector.getInstance(TaskExecutor.class);
  }
}
```

`Module1` defines how the `TaskExecutor` needs to be constructed.

In the code we use `ObjectFactory.getInstance().getTaskExecutor()` to obtain and the instance of `TaskExecutor`.

In unit tests we want to be able to replace this with a `FakeTaskExecutor` essentially we want to get an instance of `FakeTaskExecutor` when `ObjectFactory.getInstance().getTaskExecutor()` is called.

I was thinking of implementing a `FakeModule` which would be used by the injector instead of the `Module1`.

In Spring, we would just use the `@Autowired` annotation and then define separate beans for `Test` and `Production` code and run our tests with the `Spring4JunitRunner`; we're trying to do something similar with Guice.

Comment: Have you looked into mocking? Mockito is the API I'd recommend.

Comment: The `FakeTaskExecutor` could be a mock or a test double, I don't know how I could intercept the Injector inside `ObjectFactory`.
Is Mockito with PowerMock the only way to do this, if so are we using Guice incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, first things first: You don't appear to be using Guice the way it is intended. Generally speaking, you want to use `Guice.createInjector()` to start up your entire application, and let it create all the constructor arguments for you without ever calling `new`.

A typical use case might be something like this:

```
public class Foo {
  private final TaskExecutor executor;

  @Inject
  public Foo(TaskExecutor executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
  }
}
```

This works because the instances of Foo are **themselves injected**, all the way up the Object Graph. See: [Getting started](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted)

> With dependency injection, objects accept dependencies in their constructors. To construct an object, you first build its dependencies. But to build each dependency, you need its dependencies, and so on. So when you build an object, you really need to build an object graph.
>
> Building object graphs by hand is labour intensive, error prone, and makes testing difficult. Instead, Guice can build the object graph for you. But first, Guice needs to be configured to build the graph exactly as you want it.

So, typically, you don't create a Singleton pattern and put the injector into it, because you should rarely call `Guice.createInstance` outside of your main class; let the injector do all the work for you.

---

All that being said, to solve the problem you're actually asking about, you want to use [Jukito](https://github.com/ArcBees/Jukito).

> The combined power of JUnit, Guice and Mockito. Plus it sounds like a cool martial art.

Let's go back to the use case I've described above. In Jukito, you would write `FooTest` like this:

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class FooTest {
  public static class Module extends JukitoModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureTest() {
      bindMock(TaskExecutor.class).in(TestSingleton.class);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testSomething(Foo foo, TaskExecutor executor) {
     foo.doSomething();
     verify(executor, times(2)).someMethod(eq("Hello World"));
  }
}
```

This will verify that your [Mock object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), generated by [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) via Jukito has had the method `someMethod` called on it exactly two times with the String `"Hello World"` both times.

This is why you don't want to be generating objects with `ObjectFactory` in the way you describe; Jukito creates the Injector for you in its unit tests, and it would be very difficult to inject a Mock instead and you'd have to write a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. We'll review how we are using guice in the first place.